# Simple problem: Safari and CSS/Javascript Rollovers

Tags: javascript, css, safari, internet-explorer, rollover

Basically I have a bunch of `<img>` tags wrapped in a bunch of `<div>`'s, and some javascript to make them do rollovers. The page functions beautifully in IE and in Firefox, but Safari gives:

> "TypeError: Result of expression 'ImageNavigateForum' [undefined] is
>   not an object."

Where ImageNavigateForum is the ID tag of the `<img>`. (a simmelar error occurs when rolling over any `<img>` on the page.)

Necessary code follows:

```
<div id="NavigateForum" onmouseover="ImageNavigateForum.style.visibility='visible'" onmouseout="ImageNavigateForum.style.visibility='hidden'">
<a href="http://www.dmt-nexus.com/forum">
    <img id="ImageNavigateForum" src="images\NavigateForum.jpg" class="hidden" alt="" />
</a>
```

there is a matching `#NavigateForum` entry in style.css

Answer (score 2):

```
onmouseover="ImageNavigateForum (…)
```

should be

```
onmouseover="document.getElementById('ImageNavigateForum') (…)
```

I don't even know why yours works on FX and IE.

Edit: Same goes with other places where you want to get a reference to an element by it's id (like the onmouseout)

Comment: In IE <.. id="foo" ..>.. will place a property foo on the global object, Safari and Firefox both ostensibly mimick this behaviour now, maybe Safari doesn't do it for images?

Comment: Ah, I was wondering if that was an extra "feature" to make ids more like names